Plotting Grouped Datasets in Mathematica
I ran into an issue while trying to plot a grouped dataset in Mathematica. Let's say that I have some test data:
ID1 = {"SomeA", "SomeB", "SomeC"};
ID2 = {"OtherA", "OtherB", "OtherC", "OtherD"};
testData = Table[
   {ID1[[Mod[i, 3] + 1]], ID2[[Mod[i, 4] + 1]], i, RandomReal[]},
   {i, 1, 12}
   ];

This generates some data that can be grouped by column 1 and column 2, with some hypothetical x and y data in column 3 and 4.
{{"SomeB", "OtherB", 1, 0.0714486}, {"SomeC", "OtherC", 2, 
  0.883144}, {"SomeA", "OtherD", 3, 0.186458}, {"SomeB", "OtherA", 4, 
  0.000303471}, {"SomeC", "OtherB", 5, 0.28907}, {"SomeA", "OtherC", 
  6, 0.757019}, {"SomeB", "OtherD", 7, 0.451152}, {"SomeC", "OtherA", 
  8, 0.614285}, {"SomeA", "OtherB", 9, 0.158008}, {"SomeB", "OtherC", 
  10, 0.392509}, {"SomeC", "OtherD", 11, 0.563529}, {"SomeA", 
  "OtherA", 12, 0.205282}}

I'm not usually envious of python, but in seaborn this would be quite straightforward:

sns.scatterplot(data=testData, x="x header", y="y header", hue="group 1", style="group 2")
I'm having difficulty achieving the same level of clarity in Mathematica.
Let's say that we group our dataset according to column 2
grouped = GroupBy[testData, {#[[2]]}&]
We get a list of associations back:
<|{"OtherB"} -> {{"SomeB", "OtherB", 1, 0.0714486}, {"SomeC", 
    "OtherB", 5, 0.28907}, {"SomeA", "OtherB", 9, 
    0.158008}}, {"OtherC"} -> {{"SomeC", "OtherC", 2, 
    0.883144}, {"SomeA", "OtherC", 6, 0.757019}, {"SomeB", "OtherC", 
    10, 0.392509}}, {"OtherD"} -> {{"SomeA", "OtherD", 3, 
    0.186458}, {"SomeB", "OtherD", 7, 0.451152}, {"SomeC", "OtherD", 
    11, 0.563529}}, {"OtherA"} -> {{"SomeB", "OtherA", 4, 
    0.000303471}, {"SomeC", "OtherA", 8, 0.614285}, {"SomeA", 
    "OtherA", 12, 0.205282}}|>

And we can index into the new grouped dataset numerically or by strings
grouped[{"OtherB}]

{{"SomeB", "OtherB", 1, 0.0714486}, {"SomeC", "OtherB", 5, 
  0.28907}, {"SomeA", "OtherB", 9, 0.158008}}

grouped[[1]]

{{"SomeB", "OtherB", 1, 0.0714486}, {"SomeC", "OtherB", 5, 
  0.28907}, {"SomeA", "OtherB", 9, 0.158008}}

The problem is when I want to plot this data, and use the categorical information to provide legends/coloring etc.
This gets me all of the groups:
ListPlot[
  Table[
    {grouped[[i]][[;;,3]], grouped[[i]][[;;,4]]}//Transpose,
    {i, 1, Length@grouped}
  ]
]


However, it doesn't get me a legend, or allow me to perform any other formatting based on the content of column 1.
What is best practice here for:

Plotting grouped datasets with descriptive legends
Plotting grouped datasets with different markers for different groups
Plotting grouped datasets with different colors for different subgroups

I think this question hits on some of this question, but I think there are some other points that are not answered here.
EDIT 1: Added example output of Seaborn plot

Please include an image of the result generated by the python code.

Added example output

Using testData you can create nested associations then dataset.
g = GroupBy[testData, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}, #[[All, {3, 4}]] &];
gm = KeySort /@ KeySort[g];
ds = Dataset[gm]


You can write a helper function, e.g.:
f[u_, m_] := 
 ListPlot[ds[u], PlotMarkers -> m, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   PointLegend[Automatic, Normal@Keys[ds[u]], 
    LegendLabel -> Style[u, Bold, Underlined]]]

Then plot:
Show[MapThread[
  f[#1, #2] &, {Normal[Keys[ds]], {"\[CirclePlus]", "\[CircleMinus]", 
    "\[CircleTimes]"}}], PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]



I'm still trying to grok this example. I've never really used/seen a helper function like that within a plotting function. How does Mathematica handle the fact that you're calling ListPlot multiple times within MapThread? Is it essentially drawing repeatedly over the first canvas that gets initialized?

Starting with your grouped, you could do something like this:
ListPlot[
  grouped[[All, All, 3 ;; 4]], 
  PlotLegends -> Catenate[Keys[grouped]], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"B", "C", "D", "A"}]


I'm not entirely sure that's what you want, since I'm not quite seeing how it lines up with your python/seaborn example, but it's my best guess.
If you want the styles/legends to be derived automatically, then probably the best way to do that is to incorporate something in your data or something parallel to it.

I agree that this works, but I'd like to have something that's auto-generated. In reality, I have a lot more combinations than would be feasible/useful to enumerate by hand.
